# Code Blocks C/C++ IDE output file permission denied, solution

Tags: windows-7, codeblocks, eclipse-cdt, permission-denied, dev-c++

Solution to the problem where Code blocks can't compile or run output file because of 'permission denied' error. Also cannot open the file created in debug/bin of several IDE's.

This is due to application experience cache that OS gives to any running process:

Open Run window (press Windows key + R key)
Type services.msc
Find Application Experience and open it
In General tab change Startup type to Automatic
Hit Ok

This is an answer from a Stackoverflow user - Reza Ebrahimi. Thanks to him because I was about to give up.